# Intersecting two images (Sentinel 2) from each other using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

[image]

The Google Earth Engine JavaScript API is throwing me an error (ndti_Before.intersection is not a function).

How could I solve or fix my code to get an intersected image?

I'm trying to get an intersected image.

For reference use the below image.

```
// Before lockdown 

var filtered_before = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-03-09','2020-03-10'))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));
print(filtered_before);

var composite = filtered_before.median();
print(composite);

// creating visualization rbg of select area

var rgbvis_Before = {min:0.0, max:3000, bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
Map.addLayer(composite.clip(geometry), rgbvis_Before, 'FCC');

// Calculating NDWI before lockdown 
// GREEN = B3 and NIR = B8

function addndwi(image){
var ndwi_Before = image.normalizedDifference(['B3','B8']).rename('ndwi_Before');
return image.addBands(ndwi_Before);
}

//creating map or visual for ndwi

var withNDWI = filtered_before.map(addndwi);
print(withNDWI);

var composite_withNDWI = withNDWI.median();

var NDWIcomposite = composite_withNDWI.select('ndwi_Before').clip(geometry);

var ndwivis = {min:0, max:1, palette:['00FFFF', '0000FF']};

Map.addLayer(NDWIcomposite, ndwivis, 'NDWI_BEFORE');

// Creating the binary image for water and non water pixels 

var vivis_Binary_image_before = {min:0.03, max:1, palette:['black', 'white']};
Map.addLayer(NDWIcomposite.clip(geometry), vivis_Binary_image_before, 'Before Binary Image');

// Creating Water mask of the image and water values = 1

var water_mask_before = function(image) {
                              var NDWI = image.select(['NDWI']);
                              return image.updateMask(NDWI.eq(1));
};

var vivis_water_mask_before = {min:0.0, max:1, palette:['white', 'blue']};
Map.addLayer(NDWIcomposite.clip(geometry), vivis_water_mask_before, 'Before Water mask');


// Calculating NDTI for the clipped area Before lockdown
// RED = B3 and GREEN = B4

function addndti(image){
var ndti_Before = image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']).rename('ndti_Before');
return image.addBands(ndti_Before);
}

// for better visualization parameters we will use Stretch:100% for NDTI 

var withNDTI = filtered_before.map(addndti);
print(withNDTI);

var composite_withNDTI = withNDTI.median();

var NDTIcomposite = composite_withNDTI.select('ndti_Before').clip(geometry);

var ndtivis = {min:0, max:1, palette:['black', 'white']};

Map.addLayer(NDTIcomposite, ndtivis, 'NDTI_BEFORE');

**// This where I'm getting stuck**
// Intersecting 
// input= NDTI and input geometry = Water mask image

var ndti_clip_Before = Polygon.intersection(water_mask_before,NDTIcomposite, null, null);

Map.addLayer(ndti_clip_Before,'NDTI CLIP' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The error already hints at your problem. You are applying a intersect function that requires 2 inputs of type `geometry`. My guess is that the following line should be changed:

```
Polygon.intersection(water_mask_before,NDTIcomposite, null, null);
```

water_mask_before is a function and not a geometry so you probably want to get the geometry of what the water_mask_before function generates as output. That will be an image and might require you convert the mask to an geometry by using `reduceToVectors()`.

Also check your inputs, you are now providing 5 inputs where it only requires 4.

If you provide a working example that reproduces your error it is a lot easier to help you out and provide some detailed suggestions